# Azure web sites and logging

Tags: azure, logging, azure-web-app-service

I have managed to set up my azure logs, how do I test if it is working?

[This tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2014/01/29/from-the-mvps-diagnostics-and-logging-in-windows-azure-web-sites.aspx) describes how to set up a log, but not how to test it.

Answer (score 1):

You can install a site extension called "Azure Website Log Browser" which makes veiwing your logs an easy task.

For more information on how see here:
http://blog.amitapple.com/post/2014/06/azure-website-logging/

Answer (score 0):

You can test whether your logs are actually working by running some code that definitely logs information, then opening up the logs table (or blob, whatever your mechanism of choice was) in your storage account and checking whether the logs exist.

Recent versions of Visual Studio are able to examine the contents of a table. There are also some free tools out there that allow you to browse your azure storage account.